# Failed to load PDF using Response Class

Tags: php, laravel-5, dompdf

I am using Laravel 5.2, with Dompdf "barryvdh/laravel-dompdf": "^0.7.0". 
At first step, I am creating a PDF file with HTML input and saving it in storage path, which works fine. Later I have a link which helps rendering this saved PDF file in browser using Response class. 
The code snippet for that is shown below-

```
$filename = 'file.pdf';
$path = storage_path($filename);
return \Response::make(file_get_contents($path), 200, [
      'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
      'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; filename="'.$filename.'"'
]);
```

This works fine on my local machine, but throws error on pre-production and production server with alert message "Failed to load PDF".

Please need your help in understanding what's going wrong. Or else, is there any workaround I can do to load PDF file in browser?

Your help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

using response classes in laravel

```
return response()->download($pathToFile);
```

OR

```
return response()->file($pathToFile);
```

using dompdf method chaining

```
return PDF::loadFile(public_path().'/myfile.html')->save('/path-to/my_stored_file.pdf')->stream('download.pdf');
```

**EDIT**
From dompdf source the stream method requires only a filepath

```
public function stream($filename = 'document.pdf' ){
        $output = $this->output();
        return new Response($output, 200, array(
            'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
            'Content-Disposition' =>  'inline; filename="'.$filename.'"',
        ));
    }
```

so you can try `dompdfobj->stream($filepath);`

OR

i found it online

```
 $headers = [
            'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
            'Content-Disposition' => 'inline; ' . $fileName,
        ];

        return Response::make(File::get($filePath . $fileName), 200, $headers);
```

Comment: Thanks shobi, I have tried with response method, still the same issue, it works on local but fails on server. Using the PDF Class, you suggested streaming the file when we generate it, but I already have the file created, I am accessing the stored file for administrative purpose. Is there a way we can render it using the pdf path?

Comment: Sorry For the above comment. return response()->file($pathToFile); throws error "Method file does not exist."

Comment: you are using the laravel 5.2 right? the response() helper functions are global and should be avilable everywhere. just gimme a second, i m checking

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/responses#file-downloads can you check this doc link?

Comment: Thanks Shobi, I tried all of your methods, everything works on my local system, but same code shows error on server with message "Failed to load PDF". There must be some configuration file issue on server I guess.

Comment: probably the ownership issue of the storage path, you need to have read permission for the webserver on the storage path, give it full permissions then check the status, or you can change the pdf storage path to somewhere else, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

By using laravel `return response()->file('/path_tofile/document.pdf');`

You can accomplish that also by Adding `Accept-Ranges` header to response and set it to `bytes` as follows:

```
$headers = [
    'Content-Type' => 'application/pdf',
    'Accept-Ranges' => 'bytes',
];
return \Response::make('/path_tofile/document.pdf', 200, $headers);
```